# Firestore Database Rules for Documents Field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to make a document visible to all user but the field of the document visible only to the owner of the document. How can I proceed?

Comment: Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions).

Comment: sorry dear, I can't understand how to do it

Comment: Hey Elsino. It is currently not clear what you're trying and where you are stuck. With this limited information it will be hard to give you better help than the documentation already does, which is likely why Sunny posted that link. To allow us to help you better, please update your question with an example of the datab structure you're trying to secure, and the minimal rules that you've already written that reproduce where you got stuck. For more help on how to help us help you, have a look at [how to create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Firestore, you can't control the permissions for reading individual fields.  Read permissions apply to the entire document.  So, if a user is graned read access to a document, they will always have the ability to read the entire document.

If you want to restrict access to certain fields, you should put those fields in a different document, probably in a different collection (either a top level collection or a subcollection), and write a rule that restricts access to it the way you want.

Comment: I already red that information on the web, but my question is: "Is it not possible to make a User able to only see that the specified document exist, withoud reading fields?"

Comment: If the user can't read the document, then they can also not know that it exists.